# Using SESSION in a class ( can echo still get error )

Tags: php, session

I'm using a class which handles 'projects'
Now i want to assign the current language into a variable but i'm getting an error.

> Undefined variable: _SESSION

The weird thing is that i can `print_r` the session, and echo session values.
`session_start()` is called in my `index.php` where I include this class file so that's not the problem, but still i get this undefined variable error. Here's my code

```
class Projects {

    private $db;
    private $lang;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->lang = $_SESSION['la']; // This is the line that gives the error
        print_r($_SESSION); // this print_r is working! 
    } ...
```

I notice that when I call the `print_r` it gets called twice.
Once at the top of the document which is working, The second output in my class itself returns `NULL`.

### EDIT 2

When i include session_start() at the top of the class it's working but it also says

```
A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in D:\Sites\proman\class\Projects.php on line 2
```

Comment: Where did you put session_start();

Comment: Show the whole error message

Comment: And the output of `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: session_start() is at the top of index.php, and index.php includes the projects.php class file.

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in D:\Sites\proman\class\Projects.php on line 10

Comment: SESSION OUTPUT: ( [loggedin] => 1 [uid] => 1 [firstname] => miguel [la] => EN )

Comment: Check if `var_dump($_SESSION);` provides something. And check if something is in your variable with empty() `if(!empty($_SESSION['la'])) { //do output }`.

Comment: This is the var_dump : array(4) { ["loggedin"]=> int(1) ["uid"]=> string(1) "1" ["firstname"]=> string(6) "miguel" ["la"]=> string(2) "EN" }

Comment: Aha! For some reason when i call the print_r in the class it outputs the SESSION variables at THE TOP, but in my class itself it outputs NULL

Comment: Do you include the file AFTER you do session_start()?

Comment: Jup, i require the file after session_start

Comment: edited post with new info

Comment: When are you calling that `__construct` ?

Comment: What if you add `session_start()` inside of the `__construct` ?

Comment: @MaxiCapodacqua: Because the __constructor functions gets called when the class gets constructed `$projects = new projects($db);`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, I knew that, I meant if he is instantiating the object before a change on the session, or before `session_start()` at some point.

Comment: Hmh, if i add the session_start() in the construct it's also giving the session_start already defined, But when i remove it from my index.php it's working. is it good to always define the session_start in the constructor of the class instead of just in the index.php?

Comment: @MiguelStevens: I never had that issue (to be honest, I don't even use $_SESSION much), but a workaround would be, to give the __construct the variable `$projects = new projects($db, $_SESSION);` `public function __construct($db, $session) {`

Comment: @MiguelStevens IMHO, no.

The session should start outside of the class

Comment: Strange that it's not working with the session_start in the index.php

Comment: @MiguelStevens: That's not the issue and you should call session_start() at the beginning of the file where the php parser starts, to avoid header already sent errors. My guess is the variable gets overwritten. Do you care to post your index.php?

Comment: With `session_start()` at the top of your `index.php` you should not have any problems. Maybe you can use `session_status()` to debug step by step.

Comment: I'll try the session_status thanks!